# etag comparision code example

Tags: android, etag

I'm trying to simulate a process like "cache validation" in my application.
I will download a new version of my webapplication on the device (android-based), but I only want to download a new version of the files, based in a etag comparision.
Does anyone a example of how use the Etag mechanism in Android?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the ETag field from a HttpURLConnection object such as like this:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
String etag = conn.getHeaderField("ETag");
```

Of course, you will need to make sure that the server you are testing this against supports ETags.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe class "**HttpRequest**" from this library ([kevinsawicki](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request)) will help you.

For example:

```
File latest = new File("/data/cache.json");
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.get("http://google.com");
//Copy response to file
request.body(latest);
//Store eTag of response
String eTag = request.eTag();

//Later you can check if changes exist
boolean unchanged = HttpRequest.get("http://google.com")
                           .ifNoneMatch(eTag)
                           .notModified();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            Log.d("Http Response:", response.getFirstHeader("etag").toString());

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the specific implement of ***ShallowEtagHeaderFilter*** performing etag generation and validation in Spring.